# Linking two TP-Link routers via WDS not working correctly

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wds

I'm trying to link 2 TP-Link routers via WDS, but its not working. When I connect to the secondary router's wifi signal, I do not get any internet.

Can someone spot something that I'm missing?

Here are some screenshots of the **MAIN ROUTER** 
[image]
[image]
[image]

And some screenshots of the **SECONDARY ROUTER** 
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: WDS simply is not intended for two wireless routers to connect to each other.  It's meant for a *client* device to connect to a wireless router (i.e. it uses the client-server model, not peer-to-peer model).